# AFNetworking call getting delay always for api call

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, afnetworking

i am calling afnetworking api call, every time its getting more delay nearly more than 10 to 15 sec.Only for this api call. Here is my code at below.

Is there any option to use dispatch to get the response data between 3 to 5 sec atleast.

My code :

```
self.myclass.GetArraryfromURL(urlstring, inviewController: self, Withhud: false, completionHandler:{(jsonObject:NSArray,Stats:Bool) in

  NSLog("jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);
}})


func GetArraryfromURL(_ urlstring: String,inviewController viewController:UIViewController,Withhud check:Bool,completionHandler:@escaping (_ jsonObject:NSArray,_ Stats:Bool) -> Void)
    {
        if AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().isReachable
        {
//            HUD = MBProgressHUD()
//            let encodestr = urlstring.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String;
            let encodestr = urlstring.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
            if check == true
            {
                self.createhudinview(viewController, value:true)
            }
            print(urlstring)
            let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager();
            manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
            manager.get(encodestr!, parameters: nil, success:{(task,responseObject) -> Void in
                print("JSON: %@", responseObject);

                do {

                    if check == true
                    {
                        self.createhudinview(viewController, value:false)
                    }
                    let jsonResults = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (responseObject as! NSData) as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                    print("status:%@",jsonResults.value(forKey: "result"))

                    let copyarr = jsonResults.value(forKey: "result") as? NSArray;

                    let flag = true // true if download succeed,false otherwise
                    completionHandler(copyarr ?? [],flag);

                    // success ...
                } catch {
                    // failure

                    if check == true
                    {
                        self.createhudinview(viewController, value:false)
                    }
                    let flag = false // true if download succeed,false otherwise
                    completionHandler(NSArray(),flag);

                    self.ShowsinglebutAlertwithTitle(self.StringfromKey("WCi"), withAlert:self.StringfromKey("errorinretrive"), withIdentifier:"error")
                }


                }, failure:{(task,error) -> Void in
                    print("Error: %@", error);
                    if check == true
                    {
                        self.createhudinview(viewController, value:false)
                    }
                    let flag = false // true if download succeed,false otherwise
                    completionHandler(NSArray(),flag);
                    self.ShowsinglebutAlertwithTitle(self.StringfromKey("WCi"), withAlert:self.StringfromKey("errorinretrive"), withIdentifier:"error")
            })
        }
        else
        {
            let flag = false // true if download succeed,false otherwise
            completionHandler(NSArray(),flag);
            self.ShowsinglebutAlertwithTitle(self.StringfromKey("WCi"), withAlert:self.StringfromKey("Check your connection"), withIdentifier:"internet")

        }
    }
```

Now its getting delay for 10 t0 15 sec. But i need to make it atleast 5 sec . Not sure, how can i do that. I tried with `dispatch async` but i could't make it.

Any possibilities.Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The issue doesn't seems with the code. Try same API on some online tool i.e. postman. It is possible that API server is taking time to throw response back to your code.

Comment: @sinner  but android is wokring fine....thats the reason looking for any other possibilities

Comment: Is your 'jsonResults' payload heavy? i.e. try removing 'print("status:%@",jsonResults.value(forKey: "result"))' . Apart from this check the speed of your internet connection. From your current code, the time consumed by your AFNetwork get block is dependent on API response only.